# How to use custom widgets in flutterflow to image recognition with model trained by google colab or google teachable machine

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, tflite, flutterflow

I am developing an image recognition app using the TensorFlow Lite (tflite) package. I trained the model on Google Colab and integrated it with FlutterFlow. Below is my widget code. Could someone guide me on defining parameters for these widgets, ensuring proper usage? I'm unsure if my widget code is correct, and I'm facing challenges using it with a model trained on Google Colab.

Any advice on what steps I should take in this situation? [This is flutterflow platform where i am writting code for this widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60o7V.png)

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import 'index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:image_downloader/image_downloader.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class ImageRecognitionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageRecognitionWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  _ImageRecognitionWidgetState createState() => _ImageRecognitionWidgetState();
}

class _ImageRecognitionWidgetState extends State<ImageRecognitionWidget> {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  String? _imageUrl;
  List? _recognitions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _imageUrl = null; // Set to null or provide an initial URL
    loadModel();
    if (_imageUrl == null || _imageUrl!.isEmpty) {
      grabImage();
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadModel() async {
    try {
      String? res = await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/images/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite",
        labels: "assets/images/labels.txt",
      );
      print("Loaded model: $res");
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to load model: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> grabImage() async {
    String? imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(_imageUrl!);
    if (imageId == null) {
      return;
    }
    String? path = await ImageDownloader.findPath(imageId);
    print('Saved new image: $path');
    await recognizeImage(File(path!));
  }

  Future<void> recognizeImage(File image) async {
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      numResults: 6,
      threshold: 0.05,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
    );
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> stackChildren = [];
    stackChildren.add(
      Center(
        child: Column(
          children: _recognitions != null
              ? _recognitions!.map((res) {
                  return Text(
                    "${res["index"]} ${res["label"]}: ${res["confidence"].toStringAsFixed(3)}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList()
              : [],
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Column(
      children: stackChildren,
    );
  }
}
```

I have explored numerous YouTube tutorials, but unfortunately, none of them provide guidance on these aspects without a cost. Here is the link to a video that inspired me to create this app. My goal is to develop the app using my own trained model. [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0h5DAcvz6U)